# Reading and meaning of 上御道田

Tags: translation, kanji

[image: Excerpt of Map]

I am looking for the reading/meaning of the kanji shown in the attached image.
It should spell 上御道田, if I am not mistaken.
The image is an excerpt of an old map of Achimura, Nagano-ken.
I tried googling for it, but all I could find so far is [this](http://www11.plala.or.jp/samma116/25/250hakken.html).

Does anyone have any clues? Or maybe can point me to a place where I could look further?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Could you post a larger piece of the map? Ie. with more content.

Comment: [This](https://www.google.co.jp/?gws_rd=ssl#q=%22%E4%B8%8A%E5%BE%A1%E9%81%93%E7%94%B0%22) is all that shows up when googling the exact phrase...

Answer (score 3):

The page you linked clearly says 上御道 is read as うえみどう (*Ue-midō*). The page also says 上御道 was a small area located somewhere in [駒場 (*Komaba*) district](https://goo.gl/maps/Dn6fUeRqtpw).

Currently Achi village doesn't have a district name related to 御道 or 上御道 ([zip codes of Ochi](http://www.post.japanpost.jp/cgi-zip/zipcode.php?pref=20&city=1204070&cmp=1)). I checked Googleマップ and [地理院地図](http://maps.gsi.go.jp/), but found nothing relevant.

田 means "rice field", and is either read as *den* (in on-yomi) or *ta* (in kun-yomi). So 上御道田 (probably *Ue-midō den*) means "the rice field in 上御道".

Historically, there was a [宿場【しゅくば】](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shukuba) (post station) of 三州街道 (*Sanshū* highway, current [Route 153](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%9B%BD%E9%81%93153%E5%8F%B7)) in 駒場. So my speculation is that this 御道 (*Midō*, lit. "the (great) road") probably refers to Sanshū highway. 上 (*Ue*) is a kind of prefix which means "up", "high" etc. Is this 上御道田 located somewhere along 三州街道?

That's all what I could gather on the net, but the page you linked is a part of [this site](http://www11.plala.or.jp/samma116/mokuji.html), which is full of information on the history of Achi. If you really want to be sure, probably the author of this site is the best person to ask.

---

**EDIT:** Looks like うえみどう (*Uemidō*) was a small area located [around here](https://goo.gl/maps/RkAP5k5QnMG2), and it was [also written in kanji as 上見**堂** or 上御**堂**](http://www11.plala.or.jp/samma116/25/264hakken2.html) (堂 = small shrine, or [*hokora*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hokora)). The name 上御堂 appears in the official history book of Achi Village, [阿智村誌](http://misuzu-mokuji.net/detail.php?id=407001). Anyway, [ateji](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ateji) was very common in those days, so うえみどう might not necessarily refer to Sanshū highway.

Comment: Is 田 often read as デン in 地名?  Can't say I've seen it much, if ever.

Comment: @istrasci In 人名 and 地名 it's usually た/だ (藤田、本田、山田、秋田、...). But if it's a compound word that actually refers to a kind of rice field, then it's usually read as ～でん (水田、新田、[駅田](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%A7%85%E8%B5%B7%E7%94%B0)...)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, and thank you for your help! The marked place is indeed close to  三州街道 or rather, it was a place, until  三州街道 was built through it. If there is still interest, I can post the full map, I refrained from doing so for copyright reasons. It's a map out of a book I am translating atm. I am not yet sure if I will put down 'the rice field at Uemidō' or if I should write "the rice field at the upper small shrine'. Again, you have helped me quite a lot, thank you very much!